# Goreleaser failed to publish artifacts on gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, goreleaser

So I'm trying my hand on goreleaser for a personal project on gitlab (private repo) and I'm blocked with this error during build:

> ⨯ release failed after 31s                 error=scm releases: failed
> to publish artifacts: GET
> https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/night-gold/PROJECT/releases/0.0.10:
> 401 {message: 401 Unauthorized}

As you can see I'm on gitlab.com, so I did not set the gitlab_urls in my goreleaser.yml as I should be using the defaults.

My gitlabci.yml:

```
stages:
  - release

release:
  stage: release
  image:
    name: goreleaser/goreleaser
    entrypoint: ['']
  only:
    - tags
  variables:
    # Disable shallow cloning so that goreleaser can diff between tags to
    # generate a changelog.
    GIT_DEPTH: 0
    GITLAB_TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN
  script:
    - goreleaser release --clean
```

My goreleaser.yml:

```
project_name: PROJECTNAME
version: 1

before:
  hooks:
    - go mod tidy

builds:
  - env: [CGO_ENABLED=0]
    goos:
      - linux
    goarch:
      - amd64
      - arm64

archives:
  - format: tar.gz
    # this name template makes the OS and Arch compatible with the results of `uname`.
    name_template: >-
      {{ .ProjectName }}_
      {{- title .Os }}_
      {{- if eq .Arch "amd64" }}x86_64
      {{- else if eq .Arch "386" }}i386
      {{- else }}{{ .Arch }}{{ end }}
      {{- if .Arm }}v{{ .Arm }}{{ end }}

changelog:
  sort: asc
  filters:
    exclude:
      - "^docs:"
      - "^test:"
```

I generated the token with api permission as it's written in the doc, but it's not working, to be even more precise, the token has maintainer role, I tested to see if it does something.

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I've currently find something, the url used by goreleaser is something like this:

> https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/User/Project_Name/releases/0.0.11

And after multiple tests I figured out that this type of url does not work... the gitlab.com/api/ takes the projects ID and not the User/Project_Name, in my case, it's not really a 401 I get a 404 because it's targeting a non existant URL...

Still searching if there is a solution for that.

Comment: Does your access token have the `use_package_repository` rights? Are you on protected branch or tag?

Comment: I'm on the main branch, so protected, the tag should not be protected.

Comment: I removed the branch protection and that did nothing for the error